# How to make a "Unique many to many self joint" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, associations

I've read [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577147/rails-many-to-many-relation-to-self) of many to many self joints. My problem is I need it to be unique.

```rb
# app/models/word.rb
class Word < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many(:defined, 
    class_name: 'Word', 
    join_table: 'defined_definers', 
    association_foreign_key: 'defined_id', 
    foreign_key: 'definer_id')
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:definers, 
    class_name: 'Word', 
    join_table: 'defined_definers', 
    association_foreign_key: 'definer_id', 
    foreign_key: 'defined_id')
end
```

This should raise an error or not be executed:

```rb
word.definers << word.defined.first
```

Otherwise, I could have much worse undetectable errors in my app.

Comment: I assume `Word.defined` means `Word defined by [other Word]` and `Word.definers` mean `Definers of the Word`. And word can't be it's own definer. This sounds like a directed acyclic graph, and storing them in the DB is not a trivial problem (you'll not get away with in-stock associations provided by Rails). https://www.codeproject.com/articles/22824/a-model-to-represent-directed-acyclic-graphs-dag-o (feel free to update your question if it's not what you meant)

Comment: However, if you already have data in production, it may be quite hard to migrate that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicates you either need to add an unique index in database `add_index :defined_definers, [:definer_id, :defined_id], unique: true` or change your code in every place to `word.definers << word.defined.first unless word.definers.include?(word.defined)`

Comment: I have already added a unique index, but it is not enough.

Comment: If you mean that `word.defined` can never be in `word.definers` then you can add custom validation on association model `defined_definers`. In that validation check if `defined_id` is not equal to `definer_id`.